# mysql SELECT query returning error with correct syntax

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am working on a social networking site for my company and I am setting up the messaging system.

I have a table in the database called "mail" and for some reason the simplest SELECT query is returning an error.
here's the code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $from = $row['from'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    echo "<tr><td>$from</td><td>$content</td></tr>";
}
```

It is returning this error; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to='cody'' at line 1

I have used this type of query with the same syntax a hundred times before I have no idea whats wrong this time.

A few notes: The database connection works fine, "to", "from" and "content" are columns in my "mail" table.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sounds like there might be a problem with the value of `$username` - or maybe in PHP you're supposed to use `\`` instead of `'` for this sort of thing (I forget)?

Comment: can I recommend that you switch to [prepared queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) now, while you're early in development? I'd rather your site not get taken down by SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 8):

`TO` is a reserved word. Try the following instead

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE `to`='$username'";
```

> Reserved words are permitted as
> identifiers if you quote them as
> described in Section 8.2,

**[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**

Comment: +1, also please please please use [prepared queries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). People will start making usernames you don't like (`' OR ''='`)

Answer (score 0):

"TO" is also a keyword try encapsulating the field name with a backtick `

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs due to this

```
to='$username'
```

`$username` is a Php variable so check out